# Python and Huawei Wingle - getting error when I send USSD code (using huawei-modem-python-api-client library)

Tags: python, ussd

I have been working on a project using python and Huawei wingle E8372 (usb wingle) to send USSD code, fetch response which is returned by server and then also show the status of ussd  (if required).

I am using huawei-modem-python-api-client library for my project
I'm at initial stage yet I finished many things in coding like making a connection, sending sms and reboot etc.

But when I started working with USSD code, I started getting error, might be there is an error in the code so May I ask you whats the error in my code?

Here's the code:

```
import huaweisms.api.user
import huaweisms.api.wlan
import huaweisms.api.sms
import huaweisms.api.ussd
import huaweisms.api.device

ctx = huaweisms.api.user.quick_login("admin", "admin123")
print(ctx)
#Till this line it works Great



#This ussd code is to check balance: *101#
#This code doesn't work, no matter what I changed:
r = huaweisms.api.ussd.send(ctx, "*101#")
print(r)

print("\n........................\n")

r = huaweisms.api.ussd.get(ctx)
print(r)


#connected devices
device_list = huaweisms.api.wlan.get_connected_hosts(ctx)
```

When I execute this code it gives the following error:

```
c:\python_codes>py ussd.py
<ApiCtx modem_host=192.168.8.1>
{'type': 'error', 'error': {'code': '1001', 'message': ''}}

........................

{'type': 'error', 'error': {'code': '100002', 'message': ''}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message and seems as far I was able to check this code means something like "not supported by firmware or incorrect API path".

Probably should be upgraded modem firmware.

Check also this [Hilink Go package](https://github.com/knq/hilink) and resources on it for more details

Answer (score 1):

please try other function, example `huaweisms.api.sms.get_sms()` or `huaweisms.api.sms.send_sms()`

some day ago I faced to 108006 error because of wrong username (default is admin), 2 functions above worked for me with true username

update: in current version, `module huaweisms.api has no attribute ussd`; there are get_sms(), send_sms(), delete_sms(), sms_count(), sms_set_read()